# How to apply succesively the same change to each argument of a function?

Tags: r, function, arguments, iteration, apply

I am trying to figure out how to perform an elasticity analysis to a model I have developed.
To do so, I intend to apply a 10% on each parameter of the model and measure the change in the output.
I have written a simple function including all the parameter as arguments.

My challenge is that I don't know how to automatize this process to all the arguments with an apply function or a loop.

Let's take a dummy function as an example:

```
model <- function(a=1, b=1, c=1){
   result <- a+(10*b)+(100*c)
   return(result)
   }
```

I would like to apply the same change to each parameter (+10% of its value) and produce a run for each iteration.
For example, if I had to do it manually it would like this:

```
output_a <- model(a=1.1)
> 111.1

output_b <- model(b=1.1)
> 111

output_c <- model(c=1.1)
> 121
```

Ideally, all of the outputs would be in the same dataframe to easily process them in the future.
Any thoughts on this? Perhaps an existing post I couldn't find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a grid of the desired values, subset it down to those needed and then `Map` or `mapply` over it or in (3) directly generate it.

```
v <- c(1, 1.1)

# either of these would be ok
g <- expand.grid(a = v, b = v,  c = v)
# g <- do.call("expand.grid", Map(function(x) v, c("a", "b", "c")))

g <- g[rowSums(g != 1) == 1, ]

# either of these would be ok
transform(g, result = mapply("model", g$a, g$b, g$c))
# transform(g, result = do.call("mapply", c("model", g)))
```

giving:

```
    a   b   c result
2 1.1 1.0 1.0  111.1
3 1.0 1.1 1.0  112.0
5 1.0 1.0 1.1  121.0
```

**2)** There are also a number  of list comprehension packages (comprehenr, eList, listcompr) that can be used:

```
library(listcompr)
gen.data.frame(data.frame(a, b, c, result = model(a, b, c)), 
  a = v, b = v, c = v, (a != 1) + (b != 1) + (c != 1) == 1)
```

giving:

```
    a   b   c result
1 1.1 1.0 1.0  111.1
2 1.0 1.1 1.0  112.0
3 1.0 1.0 1.1  121.0
```

**3) diag** We can directly create the g matrix using `diag`:

```
g <- diag(.1, 3) + 1
colnames(g) <- c("a", "b", "c")
cbind(g, result = apply(g, 1, function(x) model(x[1], x[2], x[3])))
```

giving this matrix:

```
       a   b   c result
[1,] 1.1 1.0 1.0  111.1
[2,] 1.0 1.1 1.0  112.0
[3,] 1.0 1.0 1.1  121.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this smart solution! I wonder if there is a way to obtain only results from a single change, and not apply changes to more than one parameter at a time.
In your output, that would correspond to the lines 2, 3 and 5 only.

Comment: Have added constraint (a != 1) + (b != 1) + (c != 1) == 1 to first two solutions to limit the number of changes to 1 in each row and have added a third solution which directly generates a grid matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding constraints to subset the grid is indeed a very smart way to limit the number of changes!

Comment: Now, to go a bit further, what is there is a long list of arguments, and they all have very different numeric values (not 1 as a default, but for a=2, b=7590, c=42, etc.). Is there a way to apply the change to each parameter when they are not equal? I will try to find a solution on my own... 

Comment: Multiply the first column of g by 2, 
the second by 7590 and the third by 42: 
`g2 <- transform(g, a = 2 * a, b = 7590 * b, c = 42 * c)`  or 
`g2 <- replace(g, TRUE, Map("*", g,  c(2, 7590, 42)))`
and now use: `g2[rowSums(g != 1) == 1, ]`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the parameter names is a bit messy, but you can do the `do.call()` syntax to build a named list. You can also use `formalArgs()` to get the names of the arguments of your function

So you could do something like

```
lapply(formalArgs(model), function(arg) {
  do.call("model", setNames(list(1.1), arg))
})
```

you could also use a more tidyverse approach with `rlang` and `purrr`

```
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
formalArgs(model) %>% 
  map(~exec(model, !!.x := 1.1))
```

Comment: Sorry, I was perhaps not very clear. I do not need to change the parameter names, but rather to run the function with different input values.